# iOS: didReceiveRemoteNotification for specific View Controller class

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

**Scenario** = I have an app with a messaging functionality. Upon sending a message a push notification will also be sent to the recepient's phone. I want the user to receive Push Notifications with the "Alert" (showing a message on the screen), "Badge" (the application icon badge number in red circle), and "Sound" (sound that plays upon Push) whenever the user **is NOT** looking at the Instant Messenger screen **-** and when the user **IS** on the Instant Messenger screen, I want the user to receive the "Badge" and "Sound" **ONLY**.

**Why do I not want "Alerts" sent while on the Instant Messenger screen?**
Because the instant messenger screen already displays the message to the user when the message is loaded into the tableView. Why would I push the IM to their screen with an "Alert" when they are going to have to click off of it all the time just to read it again on the screen to reply? Wouldn't make sense.

**Why do I only want the user to receive the "Badge" when user is on the IM screen?**
This is because my app is continuously checking for the badge count of the app to increment so it will refresh the table view when the application badge is raised. I also want the "Sound" to play to notify the user audibly that the Push has come to their phone.

**Something to note** = My app is based on an architecture that includes a Tab bar controller that contains navigation controllers for each tab. If that makes a difference.

**EDIT** - summarized and simplified question.

How do you do this?... (not real code)

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    if (isOnInstantMessagingScreen) {

        //Disable Push "Alert" messages
        //Enable Push "Badge"
        //Enable Push "Sound"
    }

    else {

        //Enable Push "Alert" messages
        //Enable Push "Badge"
        //Enable Push "Sound"
    }
```

Comment: In my opinion you are asking the wrong question. You should ask how to avoid the alert taking over your screen when the app is active.

Comment: Are you showing the alert yourself?  If your application is active then the system won't show the standard push notification alert and instead will call - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo in your appDelegate.  Are you using a third party service like UrbanAirship?

Comment: Well lets say a text comes in while a user is on another screen of the app. I still want them to get the alert with the message on it.

Comment: @BrandonRoth Yes I am, Parse.

Comment: @meda How do you do that? Is there a way to have the alert message when the phone is active and then only the badge and sound active when the app is in the foreground?

Comment: @TomTesticool sure see my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst the application is open, Apple will silence the notification, therefore it is your responsibility to display an alert or play a sound. This is good news because you do not have to worry about unregistering for notification types.

To answer your first question, you can access the topMostViewController from your application delegate by

```
UIViewController *topMostViewController = [(UINavigationController *)[self.tabBarController selectedViewController] topViewController];
```

I am assuming you have setup your tabBarController as a property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

If you have more than five tabs, `selectedViewController` can be the `moreViewController` in that case you could try

```
UIViewController *topMostViewController = [(UINavigationController *)[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:[self.tabBarController selectedIndex]] topViewController];
```

You can then assign the boolean - where `MessageScreenViewController` is your message controller

```
isOnInstantMessagingScreen = [topMostViewController isKindOfClass:[MessageScreenViewController class]];
```

You will want to know whether the application was in the foreground in order to display a UIAlertView and play a sound

```
if([application applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive){}
```

You will want to show a notification and play a sound if the user is not on the messaging screen

```
if(!isOnInstantMessagingScreen){
   [PFPush handlePush:userInfo]; // Display alert - can also be UIAlertView

   //Play sound
   NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Notification" ofType:@"wav"]];
        AVAudioPlayer *notify  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile  error:nil];
        [notify play];

    //Perhaps increment badge number
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: +1];
}
```

Does this help you at all?

The final solution could look something like (**Untested**):

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    //The application is currently in the foreground
    if([application applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive){
        UIViewController *topMostViewController = [(UINavigationController *)[self.tabBarController selectedViewController] topViewController];
        BOOL isOnInstantMessagingScreen = [topMostViewController isKindOfClass:[MessageScreenViewController class]];

        if(!isOnInstantMessagingScreen){
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification" message:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"View", nil];
            alert.tag = 1;
            [alert show];

            //Play sound
            NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Notification" ofType:@"wav"]];
            AVAudioPlayer *notify  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile  error:nil];
            [notify play];

            //Perhaps increment badge number
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: +1];
        }
    } else {
        //Application is in background - When the notification is clicked on, we will get here
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0]; //Clear notification as we have clicked it, potentially could also be -1 to decrement?

        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
        BOOL isOnInstantMessagingScreen = [[navigationController topViewController] isKindOfClass:[MessageScreenViewController class]];

        //Perhaps we want to navigate to the message controller screen
        if(!isOnInstantMessagingScreen){

            //Somehow push the messaging screen onto the UINavigationController
            //This could be done here by alloc and initing the view controller
            MessageScreenViewController *viewContoller = [[MessageScreenViewController alloc] init];
            [navigationController pushViewController:viewContoller animated:YES];

            //Or perhaps by calling a function on the rootView of the UINavigationController
            RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
            [rootViewController loadMessageScreenWithUserInfo:userInfo];

            //Show tab
            [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2]; // Index of NavigationController which will contain the MessageViewController
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And here's your bonus for being super dedicated to helping me out today. See ya around Will! Your points they say i can give out in 18 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to do all that work to register and unregister for the different notifications. I'm going to go out a limb and suppose that the parse library is responsible for showing the UIAlertView.

When your app is active you get a callback in you appDelegate method

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

whenever a push notification is received.  In this case the system doesn't show an alert.  My guess is that Parse had your implement that method and made some sort of method call to the parse framework which is showing the alertView.

For reference if the app isn't active and is launched in response to a push notification then ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions will be called instead and the contents of the push notication will be in the launch options dictionary.

Just register for all three notications like normal and then handle the notifications in those two methods.

Comment: thank you so much for your responses. Yes Parse is responsible for the Push. But I think it is important to note that when I [[UIApplications sharedApplication]unregisterForRemoteNotifications] it does in fact stop the push from coming in at all. I was running into a problem just setting it to register for the "Badge" and "Sound" of the Push.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever code that is taking over your screen when you receive a push is happening  `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, so add checks for example:

```
UINavigationController *navController = ((UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController);

if ([navController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[IMViewController class]]) {
    //user is on IM screen
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Meda! This does infact answer my question, I was however already aware of another method of doing your code above. I see your point is to do it in the didReceiveRemoteNotification: method of the AppDelegate - but is there are a to say in your code something like, "if (state == isOnTheIMScreen) { //register for "badge" ONLY }  else { //register for "alert", "sound", and "badge""?

Comment: @TomTesticool please show me your `didReceiveRemoteNotification` so that I can adjust my code

Comment: I put it up there for you. There isn't much there and you may say that Parse handling the Push is part of the problem. But this is what I got right now.

Comment: Whao! Are you tell me all I got to do is that if statement in my didReceiveRemoteNotification and then I can set my application to register for just the "Badge" inside of that and it works?!

Comment: Yes thats all you needed to do, so `[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];` would go in the else block

Comment: I'm going to fiddle with this and I'll be back. (Ahnold voice)

Comment: @TomTesticool sure letme know  and im sorry I couldnt provide more code I dont know much about parse

Comment: You are a big help don't worry about it. We are both learning together. But hey I tried it and it logged me out "-[LoginViewController visibleViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16679760". **Note**: "LoginViewController" is not my IM class nor what I specified, but its saying this anyways. Any reason you can see as to why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58287/discussion-between-meda-and-tom-testicool).